# Did Dooku express his respect/resent to Darth Maul for killing his apprentice?

Tags: star-wars, darth-maul, darth-tyranus

Darth Sidious approached Dooku shortly after the Battle of Naboo (and death of Qui-Gon Jinn) to sway him to the Dark Side. He became an apprentice to Sidious, which Maul was as well.

Did Dooku express his resent or respect to Maul for killing his former padawan? Did he, say, praise Maul for his combat skills (in defeating Qui-Gon) or dislike him?

Comment: Surely Dooku would've thought Maul was dead?

Comment: @Edlothiad You can respect or resent somebody who is dead. e.g. - I respect Franklin Roosevelt even though he died before I was born.

Comment: @RichS is a dead person still considered an "ally"?

Comment: @Edlothiad Voronwë's edits have rendered our comments obsolete.

Comment: Your first comment shouldn't be deleted @RichS,  it's a good example

Comment: As far as I remember, Dooku did not express his opinion on Maul in The Clone Wars. I do not know of other relevant canon sources

Comment: As Dooku turned to the Dark Side, I do not think that the old "Master-Apprentice" bond persisted, and I doubt he had any warm feeling for his possible rival as Darth Sidious's apprentice (The Rule of Two).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Savage Opress, Maul's brother, was Dooku's apprentice for a short time. Nevertheless, I don't think they ever talked about Maul or Qui-Gon Jinn. To quote Darth Bane ***“Honor is for the living. Dead is dead.”***  Sith do not believe in afterlife, neither they hold attachments to something that is destroyed. Note that after they discovered that Maul still lives, it is Palpatine, not Dooku, who goes after him. All of this points to conclusion that Dooku simply didn't care much about what was happened. Only thing that mattered was to tie up loose end that was Maul, because he had no place in Sith plans.

Comment: Ironically in the comics, Darth Sidious talks to Darth Vader about the roles of Darth Maul and Darth Tyranus behind their backs while they're both dead!